# How can I play music from my HTC Desire Android phone in my car?

Tags: htc-desire, fm-radio

My car is a 2002 Toyota Camry and the stereo is old-fashioned like this:

- http://www.google.com/images?um=1&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=hao&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-GB%3Aofficial&biw=1440&bih=672&tbs=isch%3A1&sa=1&q=2002+toyota+camry+stereo&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

I did some research and found out that I could use FM transmitter from iRiver:

- [http://www.amazon.com/iriver-AFT-100-Mobile-Transmitter/dp/B00067LYFW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00067LYFW)

Is that the recommended way to play music from my Android without investing too much?

If yes, that also creates a new problem which is the Power Socket needs to be shared between iRiver and Android (which is power hungry). How do I solve that problem?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

I have something similar to [this Parrot handsfree kit](http://www.parrot.com/catalog/products/parrot-mki9000/) that I use for handsfree calls, but primarily for playing music from my Desire through my car stereo (which is of similar vintage).

That approach has the advantage that you can control the music from the handsfree kit, not having to worry about which pocket your phone is in.

---

> Yeah I'm curious too.. it seems to use Bluetooth. I don't think my car stereo has Bluetooth support

It does, but it handles all of that. My stereo doesn't have Bluetooth either, but the phone connects to the handsfree kit, which then hands either a mono audio stream (handsfree) or stereo (music) to the stereo's appropriate inputs.

Comment: That looks great - much better than dangling wires everywhere! +1 How does the parrot connect to the car's stereo for the music / call output?

Comment: Yeah I'm curious too.. it seems to use Bluetooth. I don't think my car stereo has Bluetooth support

Answer (score 0):

The FM transmitter solution works, but can be a bit unreliable as you drive around, moving through areas with different interference etc.  The transmitter works by sending the radio signal out at low power on a particular frequency, so if there's something bigger (like a real radio station) broadcasting on the same frequency you'll hear that instead.

I have a transmitter that can be battery-powered or plugged into the cigar lighter - it only works satisfactorily when plugged in.

The quality of the sound also depends on how good the FM reception is in your car.

As for the power issue, you can get splitters for the standard car cigar lighter; search Amazon for "car power splitter" for examples, such as:

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B001JPRLPM/ref=mp_s_a_5?qid=1293873275&sr=8-5](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001JPRLPM)

If the transmitter works for you in your car and your location, and you can put up with the wires dangling around the car, then it's an ok (not great) solution. Another simple method would be to replace your stock car stereo with one that has a 3.5mm AUX input, and plug the phone straight in.

Comment: Thanks Matt. How do I find out which car stereo would replace and fit into the slot in my Camry? Which one would you recommend which has 3.5mm AUX input?